# JIRA REST CLIENT: issue.getattachments() returns null

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am trying to get the attachments for a JIRA issue. However the getAttachments() method is returning null. The JIRA version is v6.1.4

Below is the code

```
final JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
final URI jiraServerUri = new URI("http://XXX-jira.YYY.com");
final JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, "XXXX", "YYYY");
//final NullProgressMonitor pm = new NullProgressMonitor();
final Issue issue = restClient.getIssueClient().getIssue("XXX-35238").claim();

System.out.println(issue);
System.out.println(issue.getAttachments());
```

Below are the maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-m2</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-m25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-m25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-m25</version>
</dependency>
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The "Attachments" field must be available in the "default screen". Otherwise the attachments will not be included to the response (although they are visible when viewing the issue in the browser...)

Comment: thanks.  I was running in circles for hours until I found this answer.